# Unknown Operator and x

Tags: arithmetic

I have not much  of a clue about math.

Is there any way that I can paste equations like this:

48 ? 27 * x * 16 = 82944

or this

85 ? 82 * x + 2 = 8

and get a value for x plus the correct operator (+ - or *).

These equations do not treat multiplication and division prior to adding and substracting. They are all treated equally.

Comment: What do you mean by paste? Also, since you have a variable there, both operations can be used, you will just get different values for $x$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: You can probably use any operator you'd like and then fill in the $x$ that makes it work.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. The solution is not unique.

$$(48\color{red}+27)\cdot \color{red}{\frac{1728}{25}}\cdot 16=82944.$$

$$(48\color{red}-27)\cdot \color{red}{\frac{1728}{7}}\cdot 16=82944.$$

$$(48\color{red}\cdot27)\cdot \color{red}{4}\cdot 16=82944.$$

The simplest solution (and probably the intended one) might be the one with the multiplication. I guess you have to try all of them and look which one gives a nice result.

Comment: Do you know of any way where I could copy paste that and get the result for each of the operators. It is solvable with each one, but they have to be "complete numbers" (no clue what the math term is) and cannot be negative. Or do you know how to write a function in javascript for that . :D

Comment: @user2164882 The term is *natural number* ;). I am afraid you will have to do it by hand. I mean there are ways to automate solving such equations, but in my opinion its not worth it since writing some code like this will take you hours and a lot of experience with expression trees. And there are only three cases for each equation.

Comment: well It would probably be worth it for me, because the one who solves those the fastest gets some kind of cryptoreward.

Comment: @user2164882 Then for the general approach consider starting [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree). ;) You can use it to automate solving for $x$ and trying all operators.